# A sinusoidal sketching for peak 60V applied to a diode as shown

Tags: voltage

[image: Circuit Diagram]

This is the sketch of the circuit the peak value of AC is 60V and I need to know how can I draw the graph at Vo the R1 & R2 confuses me I can't understand there effect on graph and how the DC 15V connected is going to affect the graph. Please help me with this concept and graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the diode is ideal.
when the AC supply is negative through 15 volts, the diode does not conduct(because of the 15DC voltage source) so the diode acts as an open circuit and the output voltage is the same as AC input voltage and when the AC voltage raise above 15v then diode starts to conduct and acts like a short circuit so the output voltage remains 15v until the AC voltage falls to 15v.

The amount R1 or R2 does not affect the output cause we assumed that everything in the circuit is ideal and power sources(DC and AC) can supply as much power as R1 and R2 need.

Comment: please comment why you voted me down.

Answer (score 0):

First, by KVL, we have:

\$V_O = 15V + V_D\$

Second, there are two regions of operation per cycle of the AC voltage source.  Assuming an ideal diode, they are:

(1) \$V_D = 0V\$ when \$I_D > 0\$ (the diode is a short circuit for forward current)

(2) \$I_D = 0A\$ when \$V_D < 0\$ (the diode is an open circuit for reverse current)

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I can but what about R1 & R2

Comment: @Ali, if you think carefully about (1) and (2) in my answer, it will be obvious what to do with R1 and R2.